# How to run delegate method on main thread that was invoked on a separated thread?

Tags: c#, .net

I wish to run `onSomeEvent()` on main thread because I plan to access `Clipboard`, which can only be done within main thread. If possible, I wish to do it as console application. I know I could make a `WPF` and wrap the calls in `Control.Invoke()` but I prefer not to use whole framework simply to move a method call between 2 threads. I made a simplified example below:

```
   public static class Listener {
      public static event Action onSomeEvent;
      public static void Run() {
         onSomeEvent?.Invoke();
      }
   }

   public class Program {

      public static void Main(string[] args) {
         Console.WriteLine("Main thread id: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
         Listener.onSomeEvent += () => {
            Console.WriteLine("onSomeEvent's ManagedThreadId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
         };

         Thread spawn = new Thread(() => {
            Console.WriteLine("spawned thread's ManagedThreadId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Listener.Run();

         });
         spawn.Start();

         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
```

Comment: You have to implement some sort of message queue, or other work item queue yourself. You can't just magically make a thread do something from another thread... at least not in a sane way.

Comment: That isn't really possible for a console mode app, unless you re-invent the plumbing that makes a Winforms or WPF app work.  Clearly there is no point to that when you can simply use that plumbing, Winform's Application.Run() in particular has *very* little overhead since it uses the code that is already baked into the operating system.  But look at big picture, Console.ReadLine() is a pretty useless way to do nothing, you might as well do what the thread does.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your Main thread into a blocking read loop on a queue of Tasks.  Like this:

```
class Program
{
    public static BlockingCollection<Task> MainThreadTasks = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Running on Main thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                var t = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Do Sometihg"));
                MainThreadTasks.Add(t);
                t.Wait();
            }
        );


        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread waiting Task");
            var task = MainThreadTasks.Take();

            Console.WriteLine("Main thread running Task");
            task.RunSynchronously();
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread finished Task");
        }
    }
}
```